Contentful Typescript migration does not run on Windows but runs on Mac
So, I am following Readme of contentful-migration; and same code -with credentials & keys included- works on my Mac, but not on Windows:
npx ts-node --skipProject .\node_modules\.bin\contentful-migration -s space_id -e sandbox -a access_key .\src\contentful-cms\migrations\my-migration.ts
Running this command gives below error:
C:\[project_directory]\node_modules\.bin\contentful-migration:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

The error message feels like it is thrown by Typescript interpreter; however same npx ts-node command runs successfully on Mac. I don't know what makes them behave differently and I appreciate any help. Thanks.
